# Rails creating a M:M relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user and team models joined by a membership model.

One user can have many teams and each team can have many users etc.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
End

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
End

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

I am looking for a way to simply create a memberships record however am missing something:

```
2.4.0 :026 > t = Team.last
  Team Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" ORDER BY "teams"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Team id: 42129, name: "Reds", description: "A good team", created_at: "2017-05-18 05:05:09", updated_at: "2017-05-18 05:05:09"> 
2.4.0 :027 > User.first.memberships
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Membership Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "memberships".* FROM "memberships" WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 
2.4.0 :028 > User.first.memberships << t
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Membership(#23507760) expected, got #<Team id: 42129, name: "Reds", description: "A good team", created_at: "2017-05-18 05:05:09", updated_at: "2017-05-18 05:05:09"> which is an instance of Team(#33684520)
    from (irb):28
2.4.0 :029 >
```

What am I missing here?

**Update:**
When I create a new memberships record and manually add the fk values I get this error when I try to save:

```
2.4.0 :037 > m
 => #<Membership id: nil, user_id: 1, team_id: 22641, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.0 :038 > m.save
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `class_name' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  class_eval
    from (irb):38
```

**Update2**

```
2.4.0 :022 > user = User.first
  User Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, created_at: "2017-05-15 08:17:01", updated_at: "2017-05-19 02:54:30"> 
2.4.0 :023 > team = Team.first
  Team Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" ORDER BY "teams"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Team id: 22641, name: "Reds", description: "This is a good team", created_at: "2017-05-18 01:41:00", updated_at: "2017-05-18 05:05:09"> 

2.4.0 :027 > Membership.delete_all
  SQL (1.9ms)  DELETE FROM "memberships"
 => 1 
2.4.0 :029 > m=Membership.new(user: user, team: team)
 => #<Membership id: nil, user_id: 1, team_id: 22641, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.0 :031 > m.save
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "memberships" ("user_id", "team_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 1], ["team_id", 22641], ["created_at", "2017-05-22 03:37:22.803718"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-22 03:37:22.803718"]]
   (2.1ms)  COMMIT
 => true 

2.4.0 :032 > Membership.delete_all
  SQL (1.9ms)  DELETE FROM "memberships"
 => 1 
2.4.0 :033 > m=Membership.new
 => #<Membership id: nil, user_id: nil, team_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.0 :034 > m.user_id=user.id
 => 1 
2.4.0 :035 > m.team_id=team.id
 => 22641 
2.4.0 :036 > m
 => #<Membership id: nil, user_id: 1, team_id: 22641, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.4.0 :037 > m.save
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `class_name' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  class_eval
    from (irb):37
```

Answer (score 1):

The first error message you're getting (before the **Update**) is because ActiveRecord is expecting an instance of `Membership`, and it's getting a `Team`. `User.first.teams << t` should work for that example.

As far as the error you shared in the **Update**, I didn't encounter that when I tried it, and it seemed to work fine with the relationships you gave.

```
2.2.3 :009 > user = User.first
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1>
2.2.3 :010 > team = Team.first
  Team Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams"  ORDER BY "teams"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Team id: 1>
2.2.3 :011 > membership = Membership.new(user: user, team: team)
 => #<Membership id: nil, user_id: 1, team_id: 1>
2.2.3 :012 > membership.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "memberships" ("user_id", "team_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["team_id", 1]]
   (2.3ms)  commit transaction
 => true
```

One thing to double check would be in how you're constructing the `Membership` record, and that there are no pluralization errors in the models. Passing in the actual `User` and `Team` instances to `Membership.new` or `Membership.create` should work.

Comment: Thanks as this answers problem one. Update2 makes no sense to me.